# If I've heat damaged my laptop hardware, will it affect performance, or just not work?

Tags: hardware-failure

A couple of weeks ago - when I was going home, I closed my laptop lid, put it in my laptop bag and went home.

When I got home, I found that the laptop was on, and was very hot. (Maybe 60° C - and that's spread through the whole laptop.). I suspect what had happened was that my external mouse or keyboard was still on and reviving the laptop.

Laptop seems to work fine, but I'm noticing it be sluggish. But it might be, that I sometimes use Slack and I simply don't have a enough memory. (I have been monitoring that - it certainly it maxes out sometimes).

In anycase - if the RAM or buses, or CPU in my laptop were damaged, would I know about it - or is it possible that there are errors happening in the background, that are wasting resources, that aren't immediately obvious?

Comment: If it was heat damaged it wouldn't start at all. You may have reduce your processor lifetime though. Note that laptops will shutdown if the processor gets too hot.

Comment: Depends, since when it turns off (maybe because it crashes) the hardware cools down, and then might boot again, and run for a couple of minutes until it heats up again too much. It might slow down due to the CPU running slower in order not to overheat. Only the CPU would cause this throttling, so there's software you can use to check the speed and temperature of it. Every other overheating will manifest in the system crashing. Also check the SMART data of the HDD, maybe it got affected and is having many read errors.

Comment: Excessive heat usually results in reduced component life.  There's no way to guess whether the battery, RAM, CPU, display or storage will fail prematurely.

Answer (score 0):

1. Temporary slowdown is very *common*.

   Many modern machines will reduce clock frequency to steer against overheating - it's the same mechanism as used for power-saving. There are a *lot* of temperature sensors distributed on mainboard and chips, sometimes more than one on a single chip; sometimes you can read them out in the BIOS or with specialized tools.
2. Technically, a permanent slowdown would actually be *possible*.

   Imagine reading from a hard drive on the brink of failing, which still manages to provide correct data readout - *but* with a lot of (time-consuming) retries/seek operations. This scenario isn't very probable and usually would end in permanent damage very quickly - but it would match your description of (at first) "happening in the background".

   In any case, I'd recommend to check the SMART status of your harddrive; it might indicate if there is a problem building up.